# Can't figure out how to make for loop code have a minimum and maximum value

Tags: java

I need to put in something so that when the computer asks the minimum and maximum of my values, it actually puts in those values. Unfortunately, I've gotten stuck and am unsure of what to do. Sorry, I am new to java and trying to learn it on my own.

Right now, the pattern only starts from 1 and ends at 10. However, I would like it to be so that when you type in "3 30," it starts at 3 and ends at 30.

This is what I have so far.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char operator;
        
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter initial value and maximum number: ");
        operator= s.next().charAt(0); 
        
        
        int i=1;
        while(i<=10){
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println();

        //do-while example
        int j=1;
        do{
            System.out.println(j);
            j++;
        }while(j<=10); 
    }

}
```

Comment: "so that when the computer asks the minimum and maximum of my values" is unclear to me. Do you mean "I want to prompt the user for entering two values, one to be used as minimum and one to be used as maximum." ?

Comment: "it actually puts in those values" is unclear to me. Do you mean "I want to read from input the two values entered by the user and store them in variables." ?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for being unclear about that.

Comment: "make for loop code have a minimum and maximum value" is unclear to me. Do you mean "create a for loop which count from a lower to a higher value" ?

Comment: Juding from your shown code you are collecting examples of possible loops. Can I assume that you want to write a for loop which covers the same value (1...10) as the shown loops? And, as the existing loops, does simply output values?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for being unclear about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I understand of your question, you want the user to input a min value and a max value. You are on the right track by using a Scanner object, I suggest you look at the [Scanner API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for all the methods that class has available. Particularly the `.nextInt()` method would be useful for your task. The code would look something like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please insert max value");
int max = s.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please insert min value");
int min = s.nextInt();
```

I also suggest since you are new to java, to go on websites like [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) for tutorials and courses on java.

Answer (score -1):

You want to print the numbers between a minimum and maximum, right?

So, you can use this code as example, you need to get the numbers (you can use the `nextInt()` function) to get the minimum and maximum, then use a for loop to print the values

```
public class sample {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter minimum value: ");
        int min = scan.nexInt();
        System.out.println("Enter maximum value: ");
        int max = scan.nexInt();
        System.out.println("Values:\n");
        for(int i = min ; i <= max ; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```